# Using PHP to loop through a list and format different

Tags: php

PHP pulls data from a table which is a list in HTML format:

```
<ul>
    <li>first line of text</li>
    <li>second line of text</li>
    <li>third line of text</li>
    <li>forth line of text</li>
    <li>fifth line of text</li>
    <li>sixth line of text</li>
    <li>seventh line of text</li>
</ul>
```

which is outputted by:

```
<?php echo $lines; ?>
```

However i would like to use a foreach so that i can take that list and output in the following format if possible

```
<span>first line of text</span>
<span>second line of text</span>
<span>third line of text</span>
<span>forth line of text</span>
<span>fifth line of text</span>
<span>sixth line of text</span>
<span>seventh line of text</span>
```

I want to strip out the ul and li, and replace the li by span tags, is this possible?

Comment: you need to change the format only li to span?

Comment: Start by finding the block of code that creates `$lines`

Comment: Its using concrete5 so the core controllers i think creates the var based from the db.xml file but yes just want to change the outputted li to spans and remove the UL as well. the markup of the list it actually in the database so need to change from the output i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$lines = str_replace("<ul>", "", $lines);
$lines = str_replace("</ul>", "", $lines);
$lines = str_replace("<li>", "<span>", $lines);
$lines = str_replace("</li>", "</span>", $lines);
```

or shorter:

```
$array = array("<ul>", "</ul>", "<li>", "</li>");
$replace = array("", "", "<span>", "</span>");
$lines = str_replace($array, $replace, $lines);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, ill give it a quick go and let you know

Comment: Just integrating, getting a mysql error coming back so just sorting. Had to get an inline editor form finished but its all done, just not saving so sorting that and can then confirm :)

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say :D So did this work or do you need more help? So describe your probleme.

Comment: Im getting a mysql error when saving the form so cannot get it saved to the database the ul list from the editor so then see the output yet - can you spot what its doing? i cannot see why getting the error: http://pastebin.com/aVWJfNfK

Comment: Yes I guess, but it's not really readable in your pastebin link, may you open up an other question and accept this anwere? There it will be more clear and helpfull for others looking for the same answere.
Also pls put there the plain mysql statement, to see what's wrong, and not only the exception.

Comment: Accepted, im sure will work but will give you a shout if a problem - thanks for all your help mate.